# espeak hangs when I invoke from command line - headless server

Tags: raspbian, audio-playback

For some reason espeak hangs when I try to run it.  Here is what I am getting.  Any suggestions?

```
root@nifd:/etc# espeak hi
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:990:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:618:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:556:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) The dsnoop plugin supports only capture stream
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:618:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
```

It just hangs here forever until I hit CTRL-c to kill it.

Update: I read online about running jackd in dummy mode

```
jackd -d dummy
```

So I tried that and then tried espeak again.  Still hung

```
root@nifd:/home/pi# espeak hello
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:990:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:618:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:556:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) The dsnoop plugin supports only capture stream
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:618:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
```

just hangs until I hit CTRL-c

Comment: It seems implicit here you are using SSH.  I don't know if that matters but you should make it clear if that is the case.

Comment: Good point. I was using SSH. I tried the same this from the console and got the same result.